# ListView android: I can't see my list items

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to show a ListView in my android application. (I know that I'm not extending of ListActivity, it can be the error?)  My code:

```
public class Home extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        startLocation();
        createMenuTabs();

        final String[] datos = new String[]{"Lista 1","Lista 2","Lista 3","Lista 4","Lista 5"}; 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
        ListView urban_lines_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.urban_lines_list);
        urban_lines_list.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
}
```

The XML is:

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Urbano"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
      <TextView android:id="@+id/urban_lines"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:text="@string/list_of_lines"/>
      <ListView android:id="@+id/urban_lines_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TextView is filling the whole screen, simply change its height to `wrap_content`.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/urban_lines"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/list_of_lines"/>
```

Comment: Does your app crash or do you see the TextView?

Comment: When I start the Activity in which I should see my list it's in white. But the app desn't crash. And I see the TextView

Comment: What happens when you remove the TextView from your XML and remove `startLocation();` and `createMenuTabs();` from `onCreate()`?

Comment: On createMenuTabs() I create 3 tabs so when I remove it, the content of this 3 tabs are shown in the same screen, but the list doen't appear.

Comment: Ok. if I remove the TextView it works. I don't understand why. thank you very much!

Comment: Did you change `layout_height` or `layout_width`? It could also be `list_of_lines` is too big.

Comment: Yes! That is! I put wrap_content in TextView. Thanks!